# Symfony 3: Call controller deleteAction with Ajax

Tags: php, ajax, symfony

I'm trying to delete a Symfony3 entity with ajax.

Problem is `$form->isValid()` returns false, but there are no errors on the form (or any child elements). What am I missing here?

**Controller**

```
/**
 * @Route("/{profileID}/delete", name="profile_delete")
 * @ParamConverter("Profile", options={"mapping": {"profileID": "id"}})
 * @Method("DELETE")
 */
public function deleteAction(Request $request, Profile $Profile)
{
    $form = $this->createDeleteForm($Profile);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->remove($Profile);
        $em->flush();

        return new JsonResponse(array('message' => 'profile removed'));
    } else {
        return new JsonResponse(array('message' => 'error'));
    }
}

private function createDeleteForm(Profile $Profile)
{
    return $this->createFormBuilder()
        ->setAction($this->generateUrl('profile_delete', array('profileID' => $Profile->getId())))
        ->setMethod('DELETE')
        ->getForm()
    ;
}
```

**Twig**

```
$.ajax({
  url: "{{ path('profile_delete', {'profileID': Profile.id}) }}",
  type: 'delete',
  success:function(data){
    console.log(data);
  },
  error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    console.log(textStatus);
    console.log(errorThrown);
  }
});
```

Comment: You got no form/logs problem in the profiler?

Comment: My guess is that the csrf token is missing but required.

Comment: @goto no, the profiler reports no issues. @Yoshi how should the token be submitted? I've tried sending the whole form data serialized, but also with `data: {_token: value}` and had the same result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're submitting the form without a csrf-token. A quick fix is to add the token as data:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "{{ path('profile_delete', {'profileID': Profile.id}) }}",
    type: 'delete',
    data: {
        form: {
            _token: "{{ csrf_token('form') }}"
        }
    },
    success:function(data){
        console.log(data);
    },
    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log(textStatus);
        console.log(errorThrown);
    }
});
```

`form` here is the *form name* and could also be set manually. E.g. `delete-form`:

```
private function createDeleteForm(Profile $Profile)
{
    return $this
        ->get('form.factory')
        ->createNamedBuilder('delete-form', FormType::class, null, [
            'action' => $this->generateUrl('profile_delete', array('profileID' => $Profile->getId())),
            'method' => 'DELETE',
        ])
        ->getForm()
    ;
}
```

with:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "{{ path('profile_delete', {'profileID': Profile.id}) }}",
    type: 'delete',
    data: {
        'delete-form': {
            _token: "{{ csrf_token('delete-form') }}"
        }
    },
    success:function(data){
        console.log(data);
    },
    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log(textStatus);
        console.log(errorThrown);
    }
});
```

Comment: ah, thanks! indeed the form name must have been in the request along with the token

Comment: Isn't it strange you had no forms error? I remember _token binding its error to the form parent

Comment: @goto Not quite. Without the *form name* in the post data, the form was not *officially* submitted. As such no error checking had been done yet. Suppose the we'd submit `data: {form: {}}`, then the token error should show up.